# Why doesn't Bison accept this grammar file?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, bison

When I use the command `bison -d -o parser.java parser.y` to generate a parser from my grammar file `parser.y`,  Bison produces the following error:

```
:8.8-10: syntax error, unexpected string, expecting char or identifier or type
```

Here is the file `parser.y`:

```
%{
import java.util.;
import java.io.;
%}

%start PROGRAM
%token number identifier function break call if else let read return while write
%token "(" ")" "{" "}" ";" "=" "+" "-" "" "/" "%" "<" ">" " <= " " >= " "==" "!=" "&" "|" "~" "!"
%left "+" "-"
%left "" "/" "%"
%left "&" "|"
%nonassoc "!"

%type <Node> PROGRAM FUNCTION PARAMLIST BLOCK STATEMENT IF ELSE EXPR
%type <String> identifier
%type <Integer> number
%union {
Node node;
String identifier;
int number;
}

%%

PROGRAM:
| PROGRAM FUNCTION
| BLOCK
;

FUNCTION:
function identifier '(' PARAMLIST ')' BLOCK
;

PARAMLIST:
identifier
| identifier ',' PARAMLIST
|
;

BLOCK:
'{' STATEMENT '}'
;

STATEMENT:
BREAK
| CALL ';'
| IF
| LET
| READ
| RETURN
| WHILE
| WRITE
;

BREAK:
break ';'
;

CALL:
call identifier '(' ARGLIST ')'
;

ARGLIST:
EXPR
| EXPR ',' ARGLIST
|
;

IF:
if EXPR BLOCK ELSE
;

ELSE:
else BLOCK
|
;

LET:
let identifier '=' EXPR ';'
| let identifier '=' CALL ';'
;

READ:
read identifier ';'
;

RETURN:
return EXPR ';'
;

WHILE:
while EXPR BLOCK
;

WRITE:
write EXPR ';'
;

EXPR:
number
| identifier
| '(' EXPR ')'
| '!' EXPR
| '~' EXPR
| EXPR '+' EXPR
| EXPR '-' EXPR
| EXPR '*' EXPR
| EXPR '/' EXPR
| EXPR '%' EXPR
| EXPR '&' EXPR
| EXPR '|' EXPR
| EXPR '<' EXPR
| EXPR '>' EXPR
| EXPR "<=" EXPR
| EXPR ">=" EXPR
| EXPR "==" EXPR
| EXPR "!=" EXPR
;

%%
int yyerror(String s) {
System.err.println("error: " + s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bison doesn't allow you to declare quoted token names (such as `"("`) with the `%token` declaration. It knows they are tokens; they cannot be anything else.

You use the `%token` declaration to declare symbolic names for tokens, which you will find useful when writing your lexer. In the declaration, the symbolic name comes first, optionally followed by the double-quoted alias. You can repeat that as often as you like. For example, you could write:

```
%token TK_LE "<=" TK_GE ">="
```

You can then use either the symbolic name or the alias in your grammar, but using the alias makes your grammar more readable. Also, Bison uses the alias when constructing error messages, which is a good thing since "expecting TK_SEMIC" is not a great way to communicate with a user that a `";"` was required.

Keep in mind that a single-quoted single character token, such as `'('`, is not the same token as the double-quoted alias.  In your grammar, you use '(' but attempt to declare `"("`. Had you succeeded in declaring "(", you would have gotten an "unused token" warning. Since '(' doesn't require a symbolic name, you can just remove the declaration. You will only need them for multicharacter tokens like "<=". (Note that spaces are significant inside quotes. `" <= "` is not the same as `"<="`.)

Symbolic token names are used as Java values, so their names cannot conflict with variables or Java keywords. You cannot, for example, use `break` as a symbolic token name. Trying to do so will cause compilation errors.

For this reason, it's customary to write token names in ALL_CAPS, and non-terminals in lower case.  Non-terminals names are not used in the generated code, so you can use whatever names you wish.

You reverse this convention, which will cause a variety of errors when you compile the generated parser, and which is hard to read for those of us accustomed to the standard style.

A couple of other notes:

1. The bison Java interface does not use a `%union` declaration. The `%type` declarations are sufficient.
2. You are missing precedence declarations for many operators, particularly comparison operators. That will lead to a large number of parser conflicts. Make sure you write the precedence levels in the correct order.